# Error in import oracle DUMP file with command line

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g, dump, oracle-dump

I'm trying to import a **.dmp** file that is exported from Oracle (a different environment).

In the SQL command line, I have tried the following

Open run SQL Command Line

**Step 1:** Login as the system user

```
   SQL> connect system/admin
```

**Step 2 :** `SQL> CREATE USER  UserName IDENTIFIED BY Password;`

**Step 3:** `SQL> grant dba to Bala;`

**Step 4:** `SQL> GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO Bala;`

**Step 5:**

```
 SQL> CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE TSD_UserName
         DATAFILE 'tbs_perm_03.dat'
         SIZE 8G
         AUTOEXTEND ON;
```

And finally in windows, Opened cmd.exe

**Step 6:** `C:\> imp bala/admin@localhost file=D:\abc\xyz.dmp log=D:\abc\abc_1.log full=y;`

After a while, the terminal window gives me some error message like this [image]

Note: I have also tried importing it in SQL developer and getting error messages

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the parameters "FROMUSER" and "TOUSER", so that IMP knows, where to place the imported data. If the data belonged to a differnt user in the db it was exported from, you need at least to specify the new owner of the data. If there is data from multiple users in the .exp file, you also need to specify, which user's data you want to import.

Maybe you want to have a look at this: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ

FULL=Y might work, if all required users are available in the new db. I'd probably create the user/schemas "STORES", "SALES" etc. before the next try. Usually it should be done during full import, BUT I had similar experiences years ago. I edited the dump file and copied all the "CREATE USER/SCHEMA/TABLESPSACE" statements into the comand line window, executed them  and then the import worked fine.

btw: if you want to store all imported objects in the new tablespace, FULL=Y won't do, exept all of them are already configured to use it as default tablespace in your dump file.

Comment: Getting the error message `IMP-00031: Must specify FULL=Y or provide FROMUSER/TOUSER or TABLES arguments`

Comment: Tried but getting `Import terminated successfully without warnings`. But this time there are no error messages

Comment: I would think, that "successfully" means, that the import did succeed. You should be able to find the data, where specified.